# Looking for library to concat relative / full urls. 

Tags: bash, url, unix, erlang, web-scraping

I'm writing a scraper program. I collect all the links on a page. They might be relative paths. For example:

```
foo.html
/foo.html
../foo.html
../../foo.html
```

I can concat them to the url of the page (basepath) they are on, but that isn't completely straightforward. For example:

```
http://www.example.com/foo + /bar.html = http://www.example.com/bar.html
http://www.example.com/bla/?foo=bar + ../foo.html = http://www.example.com/foo.html
```

I am wondering if there is an Erlang Lib, C Lib or a CLI program that can figure out the right concatenation for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as CLI goes, `wget` has the `--base` switch:

> ```
>   -B URL
>   --base=URL
> ```
>
> Resolves relative links using URL as the point of reference, when reading links from an HTML file specified via the -i/--input-file option (together with --force-html, or when the input file was fetched remotely from a server describing it as HTML). This is equivalent to the presence of a "BASE" tag in the HTML input file, with URL as the value for the "href" attribute.
>
> For instance, if you specify http://foo/bar/a.html for URL, and Wget reads ../baz/b.html from the input file, it would be resolved to http://foo/baz/b.html.

So if you exec'd it to output the file to stdout and read it with your erlang script, that should work.

Comment: Worked exactly as I needed. Thx

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ex_uri:resolve/2](https://github.com/extend/ex_uri/blob/master/src/ex_uri.erl#L119).